# Как работает trigger('reset')?

Tags: jquery

Код

```
form.trigger('reset');
```

сбрасывает все поля формы. Но хотелось бы подробнее разобраться как это работает. Работает только на формах или может и на инпутах? Может, есть какие-то подводные камни?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Указанный метод программно вызывает событие `reset` для `form` с соответствующими обработчиками, именно `trigger('reset')` будет работать для любых элементов у которых есть событие `reset`.

Собственно метод `trigger` можно использовать для программного вызова любых событий обрабатывающихся для выбранных элементов.

Так можно работать и с собственными событиями, вот например вместо текста `test` отображается подставленное значения `triggered!` после обработки события `myEvent`

```js
$('input').on('myEvent', function() {
  $(this).val('triggered!');
});
$('input').trigger('myEvent');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="test">
```